# What should we do about really long MathJax?

Tags: discussion, mathjax

I recently came across [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/798551/15886), which involved some pretty precise calculations. Here's how it rendered in my browser<sup>*</sup>:

[image: Screenshot of answer 798551]

Two questions arise:

- What is the desired technical behavior? Should the MathJax there really cut off the sidebar?
- What is the desired community behavior? Should users post MathJax this long?

For what it's worth, adding `overflow-x: hidden` to the `div.post-text` truncates the output as expected.

---

<sup>* Google Chrome 33.0.1750.149 on Linux Mint 16 Cinnamon ×64</sup>

Comment: Ideally I would have like to have put latex inside of scrollbars, does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: @DanielV I tried, and gave up. I actually stopped short of throwing the kitchen sink at it, so maybe there is still a way, but I am not so hopeful anymore.

Comment: @J.W.Perry Thanks for looking, if you ever find a way, feel free to edit my post (or any post of mine you think you can improve, it is welcome).

Comment: @WChagrin In hindsight, now I realize I missed the obvious, since the denominator is a power of 10 the decimal would have been exact...oh well~

Comment: MathJax is able to do [automatic line-breaking](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/output.html?highlight=linebreak#automatic-line-breaking). This is not active by default. The community could ask stackexchange to modify their MathJax configuration.

Comment: @DanielV: This inside a stylish script produces the desired behaviour, I believe: .MathJax_Display{overflow: scroll;}

Comment: @chaosflaws How do you use it?  Can put you an example into an answer so I can see it?

Comment: @DanielV That would be something the StackExchange developers would have to add; it goes in the CSS stylesheet.

Comment: Awww, but maybe we could make a meta thread recommending this.

Comment: @DanielV You can try it yourself by right-clicking, pressing "Inspect Element," going into the `<head>`, and adding the relevant `<style>`.

Comment: See my answer to use it locally.

Answer (score 13):

For now (until a built-in approach comes along), one can apply the fix that Goos just made by using `\atop` for fractions.  That is, wrap the text ***as long as the intent is clear from context.***

Example of `\atop`
$$\frac{{
14545454540916238222253308031039403263876427137099 \atop
728738149747953197899302063661139633020606426446001
}}{10^{101}}$$
Code:

`$$\frac{{
14545454540916238222253308031039403263876427137099 \atop
728738149747953197899302063661139633020606426446001
}}{10^{101}}$$`

Comment: Does anyone know if there is a way of getting the line break to be automatic? I thought a minipage would work, but alas they seem not to work in mathmode.

Answer (score 4):

Temporarily, a solution that creates sidebars is the following. Use an extension for your browser that allows to use user-defined stylesheets (for Firefox, Opera and Chrome this would e. g. be [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/stylish/)). Then, add the following code:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document domain("stackexchange.com") {
.MathJax_Display {
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
}
```